# Transforming a PC Laptop into a Multi-Platform to run either Windows 7 or Mac OS X SL at different times

Tags: windows-7, mac, partitioning

I am not looking to debate the values of Microsoft or Apple here.

My question may seem basic, I am just getting underway in this area.
I don't have the bank roll to get a MAc configured to certain specs that I need and simply partition it and install Windows 7.

But I have the funds to get a Windows 7 System and partitioning it to install OSX SL.
Many people have told me that I run  into to many problems and have to reconfigure the Bios & certain Registery keys.

I feel that I am not getting the best advice on proceeding forward and came across this group with the hope that someone may have an answer.

I'll be using the Windows 7 for various analysis and the OSX SL for processesing audio video. Sometime running together other times independently.

I guess is it just unfeasible to run Windows 7 Laptop partitioned with OSX on the other side without moding out the bios & registery keys

or just save until I have the funds for the configured mac and partition it with the Windows 7 on the  other side? Is ther an even beteer solution?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: It is easy and legal to install Windows (7) and OS X (Snow Leopard) on a Mac. It is neither on a PC.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the answer is no. You can't easily get OS X Snow Leopard running on a run of the mill PC. Not on hardware, not in a virtual solution. Your best bet is typically buying a standardized laptop that someone has already created an image for that contains all the hacks to try and get OS X working. Even these are riddled with problems. If you want OS X buy a Mac. Sorry there isn't a better answer. I researched this a long time awhile back because I wanted to check out iPhone development and was amazed the only solution was a Mac and that the only realistic way to run OS X was on Apple hardware.

Comment: My original answer isn't as true as it used to be. The community has  come a long way towards porting OSX towards broader compatibility. It is much more possible at this point than it used to be.